# angular jstree does not showing

Tags: angularjs, jstree

I am trying to show a ngjstree in loaded ng-veiw but the tree does not showed up
here is my html definition :

```
<div js-tree="treeConfig" ng-model="treeData"  should-apply="vm.applyModelChanges()"></div>
```

and here is the controller I inject into angular :

```
app.registerCtrl('OrgChartCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.treeConfig = {
        core: {
            multiple: false,
            error: function (error) {
                alert('treeCtrl: error from js tree - ' + angular.toJson(error));
            },
        },
        version: 1
    }
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        alert("");
        $scope.treeData = [
            { id: 'ajson1', parent: '#', text: 'Simple root node' },
            { id: 'ajson2', parent: '#', text: 'Root node 2' },
            { id: 'ajson3', parent: 'ajson2', text: 'Child 1' },
            { id: 'ajson4', parent: 'ajson2', text: 'Child 2' }
        ];
        $scope.treeConfig.version++;

    });

    this.applyModelChanges = function () {
        return true;
    };
```

I also try to do this without ViewContextLoaded , but it didnt work out too.

any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot to add  'ngJsTree' to my angular app module collection. see :

```
var app = angular.module('App', [
    'ngGrid',
    'ngJsTree',
    'ngRoute'//   
]);
```